# KeyUp event on form wont run? c#

Tags: c#

I wonder why this code never runs when I release a key.

```
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It works!");
    }
```

In designer this code is added as usual:

```
this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyUp);
```

However events like Form load works perfect. Is there any common solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to true, this should work with your code.

Answer (score 2):

If the form has other controls on it try setting the Form.KeyPreview property to true:
[Key Preview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that there aren't any active control on the current form. Put this code in Form.cs

```
 this.ActiveControl = null;
```